# Visual Studio alternatives on Ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio-code, c#

Are there any alternatives for Visual Studio on Ubuntu?
I searched on Google and I could not find anything.

Comment: There is Atom which is free, but if you want something which look-like more *professional*, you can use CLion (software from JetBrain company)

Answer (score 1):

Your question leaves a bit to be desired, but from what I interpret you are asking for IDEs with C# support that can run on Ubuntu.

I would highly recommend Visual Studio Code ([link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp))

Alternatively you have JetBrains Rider, which is a fabulous, but paid IDE.

If your question is if you can run Visual Studio on Ubuntu, the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for IDE then MonoDevelop or Visual Studio Code are good alternatives.